# How can I get loops to run sequentially without locking GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, pygtk

I'm writing a photobooth program in Python on my Raspberry Pi 2 and it worked if I just want to take one picture or use auto focus once. I'm trying to write a function "scheduler" that waits 4 seconds then runs auto-focus, then waits 4 seconds to take picture 1, waits another 4 seconds for picture 2 and waits 4 seconds for picture 3 while updating a status bar in PyGTK. But when the "scheduler" function is called it goes through and starts all the while loops at the same time.

I tried putting the while loops in separate functions and running them as threads and using `threadx.start()`, `threadx.join()` commands under each thread call. I suspect the way `gobject.timeout_add()` function is preventing blocking, which I need to keep the GUI updated and the live preview running, but I also can't figure out how to get blocking when I need it. I also started scheduler as a thread and used `time.sleep(1)` in each of the while loops and it acts behaves how I want it to except the GUI disappears after the first image gets processed and I can't find any error message to explain it.

I've been working on this for weeks and would happily pay someone to help me get this finished via email. I live in a rural area and have had a very hard time finding someone locally to help. I can paypal... please contact me at derosia at the popular google email service. If you have a camera supported by gphoto2 and a usb tether that would be a bonus.

```
class Photobooth(gtk.Window):

    def set_statusBar(self, status):
        self.statusBar.label.set_text(str(status))    

    def focus_counter2(self, counter):
        if counter > 3:
            self.set_statusBar("Get into position!")
        elif counter > 0:
            self.set_statusBar("Focusing: " + str(counter-1))
        else:
            self.set_statusBar("Focusing: " + str(counter-1))
        self.focus_function() #runs the function for auto focus     

    def countdown_function(self, counter, image_name):
        if counter > 1:
            self.set_statusBar(str(counter-1))
        elif counter > 0: 
            self.set_statusBar("Keep Smiling!")
        else:
        self.photo_cb(image_name) #runs the function to take an image           


    def scheduler(self, widget, data = None): 
        global ftp_path
        global image_names
        global countdown_timer        
        image_names = []

        counter = countdown_timer
        while counter > 0:
            gobject.timeout_add(counter * 1000, self.focus_counter2, countdown_timer-counter)
            counter -= 1        

        counter = countdown_timer
        while counter >= 0:
            image_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")        
            gobject.timeout_add(counter * 1000, self.countdown_function, countdown_timer-counter, image_name)
            counter -= 1        
        image_names.append(image_name + ".jpg")

        counter = countdown_timer
        while counter >= 0:
            image_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")        
            gobject.timeout_add(counter * 1000, self.countdown_function, countdown_timer-counter, image_name)
            counter -= 1        
        image_names.append(image_name + ".jpg")

        counter = countdown_timer
        while counter >= 0:
            image_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")        
            gobject.timeout_add(counter * 1000, self.countdown_function, countdown_timer-counter, image_name)
            counter -= 1        
        image_names.append(image_name + ".jpg")    


    def __init__(self):
        super(PictureBox, self).__init__()

        startB_image = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_YES, gtk.ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR)
        startB = gtk.Button()
        startB.set_image(startB_image)
        startB.set_tooltip_text("Start countdown")
        startB.connect('clicked', self.scheduler, None)
```

Comment: Why are you using the scheduler? Is there a reason you can't just call `gobject.timeout_add()` at the end of each successive timeout handler?

Comment: @andlabs I think I need to wrap the commands up in some function so that I can set them all off with one GUI signal. I've got a a gtk.Button() called startB that kicks off scheduler when it's clicked. Is there another way to do it? I also think the issue gobject.timeout_add() is that it's supposed to go kick something off and then continue running the rest of the main thread. I just don't know anyway to make those other statements conditional on the first statements finishing their whole task without crashing my program.

Comment: Yes, `gobject.timeout_add()` queues something to run at a time no earlier than the timeout you specify. It does not wait for anything to run before returning. What I'm saying is that rather than have the scheduler, you simply `gobject.timeout_add()` the first operation's function; when that function returns, it calls `gobject.timeout_add()` for the second operation's function, and so on. That should be an easy solution to a few of the problems you just stated...

Comment: @andlabs thank you! I was using the `gobject.timeout_add()` function and didn't really know how it worked until you just explained it. Total aha moment. I'll take another stab at it this afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [andlabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910094/how-can-i-get-loops-to-run-sequentially-without-locking-gui#comment46082781_28910094) I solved this the way he suggested:

Call a function and have each function call the next one when they finished what they were doing. Then to make sure it looped through the proper number of times I just passed along a counter to each function that got iterated at the end of each loop, `image_number`. It seems to work.

```python
class Photobooth(gtk.Window):
    def set_statusBar(self, status):
        self.statusBar.label.set_text(str(status))    

    def focus_counter1(self, widget, data=None):
        global countdown_timer
        counter = countdown_timer
        while counter > 0:
            gobject.timeout_add(counter * 1000, self.focus_counter2,
                                countdown_timer-counter)
            counter -= 1

    def focus_counter2(self, counter):
        if counter > 3:
            self.set_statusBar("Get into position!")
        elif counter > 0:
            self.set_statusBar("Focusing: " + str(counter))
        else:
            self.set_statusBar("Focusing: " + str(counter))
            self.focus_function()
            gobject.timeout_add(1000, self.countdown_clicked, 1)

    def countdown_clicked(self, image_number): 
        global countdown_timer
        counter = countdown_timer
        while counter >= 0:
            gobject.timeout_add(counter * 1000, self.countdown_function,
                                countdown_timer-counter, image_number)
            counter -= 1  

    def countdown_function(self, counter, image_number):
        global images_per_sequence
        if counter > 1:
            self.set_statusBar(str(counter-1))
        elif counter > 0: 
            self.set_statusBar("Keep Smiling!")
        else:
            image_name = datetime.datetime.now()
            self.photo_cb(image_name.strftime("%Y_%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))    
            if image_number < images_per_sequence:
                gobject.timeout_add(1000, self.countdown_clicked,
                                    image_number + 1)

    def __init__(self):
        super(PictureBox, self).__init__()

        startB_image = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_YES,
                                 gtk.ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR)
        startB = gtk.Button()
        startB.set_image(startB_image)
        startB.set_tooltip_text("Start countdown")
        startB.connect('clicked', self.focus_counter1, None)
```